# Are Network, or Port Assignments the physical router port as opposed to the logical (software configuration) router port?

Tags: port, dmz, openwrt

I've been looking at the [port assignments on my router](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/buffalo/wzr-hp-g300h#network.port.assignments) in the linked Open-WRT Wiki, and I'm not sure if the column that reads `Network` is the actual physical port, or if the `Port Assignment` is the actual physical port.

Note that I'm also reading about [how to setup a DMZ on OpenWRT](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/dmz) and that's how I got to the port [assignments document](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/buffalo/wzr-hp-g300h#network.port.assignments) in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be a bit confused, it doesn't say `Network` and `Port Assignment`, it says `Network Port Assignment`.  What it is telling you is that the firmware (WRT) refers to the physical LAN port #4 on the router as port 0.

Notice this `I'm using port 0, which is actually labeled as Ethernet port 4 on my physical router.` from [how to setup a DMZ on OpenWRT](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/dmz).

Comment: So those aren't table headers, I just thought I saw table headers...so if they say port 0 | lan 4 which side refers to the physical port?  port 0 or lan 4? lan 4?

Comment: Lan 4 is the physical port.